# NFS mounted userdir in httpd on CentOS

Tags: nfs, httpd, centos6.2, mod-userdir

I am using httpd server on CentOS (with SELinux enabled).
I want to use UserDir (public_html)

If I create the user on local system it works but when I give the path on NFS shared system it gives 404 error.

I am using this directive: `<Directory /nfs/*/*/public_html>`

If I try to access http://domain/~user
In error logs of httpd it says `/var/www/html/~user not found`. Somehow it is not going to path `/nfs/students/user/public_html`.
What's the solution for this?

I have set the boolean with `setsebool -P httpd_allow_nfs on` and 
nfs is mounted with options `defaults,nosuid,nodev` (can I add noexec to it)

Comment: What, EXACTLY, does the error log say.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Checkout https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_userdir.html

The UserDir directive is used to tell apache how to transform those `http://domain/~user` requests to local path.

Search for the UserDir setting in your apache configuration and set it to:

```
UserDir /nfs/students/*/public_html
```

or append the new pattern (UserDir accepts multiple patterns).

Comment: Thanks that solved it :) But now error is 403. Do I have to do anything other than setting `httpd_allow_nfs` to blue ?

Comment: You are welcome.

Comment: 403 should be related to permissions to access the folder (most likely). The 'user' folders should be readable by user your apache server is running as (`www-data`, `www`, `web` or `apache` some user id like that). Find the user id, switch to user (using `su` to switch to `root` first, then `su www-data` to switch to the apache user. The try visiting your /nfs/students/*/public_html, if you are unable to read files, apache wont be able to read either. Then you'd have to fix the permissions to the directory.